# unit Test cases for spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

I have written 1 unit Test for 1 single public method and need help from other methods of customer controller which I can refer to and write for other controllers and services.

CustomerController

```
 @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class CustomerController {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerController.class);
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    
    public List<Customer> getAllcustomers(){
        return customerRepository.findAll();
    }       
    
    **public Customer createcustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        log.info("inside customer add ***********");
        return customerRepository.save(customer);
    }**
    
    **public ResponseEntity<Customer> getcustomerById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("customer not exist with id :" + id));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(customer);
    }**

    **public ResponseEntity<Customer> updatecustomer(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Customer customerDetails){
        Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("customer not exist with id :" + id));
        
        customer.setFullName(customerDetails.getFullName());
        customer.setPhoneNumber(customerDetails.getPhoneNumber());
        customer.setPhone2(customerDetails.getPhone2());
        customer.setDistrict(customerDetails.getDistrict());
        Customer updatedcustomer = customerRepository.save(customer);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedcustomer);
    }**
    
    **public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Boolean>> deletecustomer(@PathVariable Long id){
        Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("customer not exist with id :" + id));
        
        customerRepository.delete(customer);
        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }**
    
    
}
```

Below is the Customer Model - which I am using

```
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String fullName;
    private int phoneNumber;
    private int phone2;
    private String email;
    private String district;
    
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public int getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(int phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

}
```

UnitTest for Customer.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CustomerControllerTest {

    @Mock
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    
    @InjectMocks
    CustomerController customerController;
    
    @Test
    public void testGetAllcustomers() {
        when(customerRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(getCusts());
        List<Customer> res = customerController.getAllcustomers();
        assertEquals(res.size(),1);
    }
    
    public List<Customer> getCusts(){
        List<Customer> custs = new ArrayList<>();
        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.setFullName("Dinga");
        custs.add(c);
        return custs;
    }
}
```

Like the above Unit Test cases, I need other methods also. Marked in Bold for which I need Unit Test cases.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand. What is your actual problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: want to do unit testing for my controller code for that i need help. i have created for one public method. For other public methods. below the reference code from above. 
    **public Customer createcustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        log.info("inside customer add ***********");
        return customerRepository.save(customer);
    }**

Comment: What type of controller is that? REST?

Comment: Yes. It is a Rest contoller.

Comment: Then you should add the proper mappings for each method.

Answer (score 0):

For testing a rest controller, it's recommended to use mockMvc. This acts like a rest client, but it does not actually start the server. Instead it uses the spring classes to call your code in almost the same way as if it were processing a real HTTP request. MoockMvc will perform the conversion of your data to Json and retrieve a Json result. Here's the official documentation, with some examples on how to use it: [springdoc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/). Using ObjectMapper (or JacksonTester, which uses an ObjectMapper) you can deserialize the respone into objects.

```
@WebMvcTest(CustomerController.class)
@ComponentScan("com.your.base.package")
class ControllerTest{
    @MockBean
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void test1(){
        when(customerRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(<whatever you want>)
        // call mockMvc 
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```